# How to Disable Microphone in a Secure Fashion?

Tags: windows-7, security, microphone

Like most laptops my laptop has a built in microphone. I don't use it for anything, so I consider it a bit of a liability. Due to the fact that I'm paranoid and don't want this hardware to be used to breach my privacy, I'd like to disable it. What is the most secure way of disabling it (short of physically ripping it out of my computer)?

This is in Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the volume icon in the system tray, select "recording devices"

.[image]

Once the window opens, right click on the microphone and select "disable"

.
[image]

Comment: That's not secure enough. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Some laptops will let you hardware disable it.  Since this is actually a question, I'm guessing that's not the case.  You could disable the device in device manager(easy) or add a poisoned '.inf' file for your audio device(complicated).